# Application throws an error after relaunch

Tags: android

My application throws an error when I attempt to start it from "Recent applications". Problems :

1. Error appears only if application was inactive (stopped) for a long time (approximately one hour). I can't catch this error by myself - when I'm killing process by myself and then relaunched it there is no errors!
2. I can't see Exception log in debugger, since it's disconnects after so long time.

How can I catch such kind of errors in debugger? Looks error appears only when OS kills application by itself.

**EDIT**

I didn't overrided `onResume` method. Just `onStart`, and there is nothing special except instantination of my SQLiteOpenHelper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there might be an issue in your

```
OnResume
```

call. What is your application doing? Is it using a location manager? Does it have services or threads that need to be restarted? More infomation please.

Look through the Android application lifecycle chart:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

It should help you understand what's going on. If all else fails, add a lot of logging to logcat and see what the output looks like on your end. As long as you don't unplug the device, you shouldn't lose that in Eclipse. If you do, you can always run "adb logcat" from the command line or shell to see exactly what's happening.

Comment: Not a problem. Take a look at why it's throwing an error (my guess is going to be a NPE), if you are still stuck at that point, please feel free to post your logcat and I can help you further from there.

Answer (score 2):

even if your app is in  paused/stopped state, log cat will still be working as long as device is connected. make sure you selected all logs options in windows > devices > all logs instead of  windows > devices > com.your.project .
so when you will try to relaunch crash must be recorded in logCat

if still have any issue, install logcat app from market and refer it for logs.